# How to add delay or offset to sync webvtt subtitles in html5 native video player?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, video-player, webvtt

My video and webvtt subtitles are not synced. Is there a JavaScript way to manage webvtt subtitle synchronization/delay/offset in html5 native player?

I found this lib (https://github.com/florinn/vtt-shift) but it rewrite the webvtt file on disk. I'd prefer a client side way to resync with the video.

```html
<video>
    <source class="videosource" src="{{media}}?play=true" type="video/mp4"/>
    <track kind="subtitles" label="Default" src="{{subtitle}}" default>
</video>
```

Comment: You can use the textTrack API or cueRegions but it's not worth the trouble. You should edit it using [Subtitle Edit](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases) If a simple VTT file is off, it's not 100% sure thing that you'll successfully resync it on the fly. A correctly formatted and synced VTT is 100% reliable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I made a lib to live change subtitles position, style and offset.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vtt-live-edit